# Accessing a particular member of any array

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate through my arraylist of classes to print out every method in that class. However, this keeps repeating the same methods of the first class over and over again rather than iterating through the list of classes and printing the methods of each class. I'm doing something stupid but I can't see it. Can anyone help me please ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods().length; j++) {

        System.out.println(classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods()[j].getName());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry guys the fault is the declaredMethods() function. My mistake.

Comment: Could you show us what classes contains (is initialized) ?

Comment: Can't see any problems (though possibly I'm being stupid too), have you checked that classes itself is being filled correctly? Also, what methods is it printing? do they change if you change the first class?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is right. The observed effect is that your code will print overloaded methods.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    public int bar(){
        return 1;
    }
    public int bar(int i){
        return i;
    }
}
```

With your code it will return:

bar
bar

You could add the names into a Set and when you are done with the current class print out the set.

```
for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
    Set<String> methodNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods().length; j++) {
        methodNames.add(classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods()[j].getName());
    }
    System.out.println(methodNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. My best guess is that there is something wrong with your `classes` arraylist. If you are using an IDE that allows you to step through your program I recommend using that. Otherwise, I would put print statements before and after the `j` for loop that print out the class name or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try Storing it in a reference and Printing like this ,maybe something goes wrong in the **LinkedInvocations**

```
for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods().length; j++) {

         Method[] m=classes.get(i).getDeclaredMethods();
    System.out.println(m.[j].getName()); 
    }
}]
```